# Wild card file path comparison

Tags: python

I have a folder with a number of sub folders:

```
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\port_1m
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\job_lists
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\job_lists_bu
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\job_lists_bu2
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\roll_185_oe_2018-09-07
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\roll_186_oe_2018-09-14
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\roll_187_oe_2018-09-21
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\roll_4_oe_2015-03-20
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\roll_5_oe_2015-03-27
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\roll_6_oe_2015-04-03
```

If the final folder in the path starts with 'roll' I would like to then interrogate these folders.  I am trying to find the folders using the following:

```
def main():

 folder = 'C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\'

    for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):

        if dirname == folder+'\roll_*':
            print('dirname')
```

So the current expected output would look like:

```
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\roll_185_oe_2018-09-07
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\roll_186_oe_2018-09-14
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\roll_187_oe_2018-09-21
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\roll_4_oe_2015-03-20
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\roll_5_oe_2015-03-27
C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\roll_6_oe_2015-04-03
```

However I am not getting any output. I think maybe I've set the wildcard comparison up incorrectly but am not sure.  How can I return the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues. First, remember to use raw string whenever you have a slash, like this:

```
folder = r'C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/port_a\'
```

Second, you cannot expect Python knows your globbing syntax with `==` comparison. However, as you are doing prefix match, then just check the prefix:

```
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    if dirname.startswith(folder+r'\roll_'):
        print('dirname')
```

But indeed, you can simply use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html) module in Python to do all this loop stuff:

```
import glob
for dirname in glob.glob(folder+r'\roll_*'):
    print(dirname)
```